# Why doesn't SAGE understand reduced expressions mod p in a finite field extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, finite-fields, sagemath

Suppose I have a finite field $\mathbb{F}_{13}$ and I would like to adjoin an element, $\zeta$, with order $3$, since $\mathbb{F}_{13}$ does not contain one. So consider $\mathbb{F}_{13}(\zeta)$. Then $\zeta$ is a solution to $x^3 - 1 \equiv (x - 1)(x^2 + x + 1) \equiv 0 \mod p$ and so $\zeta$ is a solution to $x^2 + x + 1$.

Then $((\zeta - 1)\zeta)^2 \equiv \zeta^2 + \zeta + 11 \equiv \zeta^2 + \zeta + 1 + 10 \equiv 0 + 10 \equiv -3 \mod 13$.

```
sage: R = PolynomialRing(GF(13),'x')
sage: x = R.gen()
sage: S = R.quotient(x^3 - 1, 'zeta')
sage: zeta = S.gen()

sage: expand ((zeta - 1)*zeta)^2
sage: ((zeta - 1)*zeta)^2 == -3

zeta^2 + zeta + 11
False
```

Although SAGE recognizes the expansion, it does not recognize that the expansion can be reduced (mod 13) to -3. Is there something wrong with my code or this a limitation of computer algebra systems?

Comment: Don't know about SAGE, but $3$ is of order three in $\Bbb{F}_{13}$ and
$$x^3-1=(x-1)(x-3)(x-9)\in\Bbb{F}_{13}[x].$$ Fact: the field $\Bbb{F}_q$ has an element of order $\ell$ if and only if $\ell\mid q-1$. Also, I would guess that you only defined the quotient ring $\Bbb{F}_{13}[x]/\langle x^3-1\rangle.$

Comment: $\zeta^3-1=0$ does not imply $((\zeta-1)\zeta)^2=-3$. For example, you could have $\zeta=1$ ($\implies 0$) or $\zeta=3$ ($\implies (2\cdot3)^2=-3$). Maybe try `R.quotient(x^2+x^2+1, 'zeta')`

Comment: Also, I think for GF(p) you are fine just assuming that it stores the representative classes as integers, but in general I would write GF(p^n, repr='int') to force the representatives to be integers.

Answer (score 2):

What you have defined is ${\mathbb F}_{13}[x]/(x^3 - 1)$. This is *not* a field, since $x^3 - 1$ is reducible over ${\mathbb F}_{13}$. Instead
$${\mathbb F}_{13}[x]/(x^3 - 1) \cong {\mathbb F}_{13}[x]/(x-1) \times {\mathbb F}_{13}[x]/(x-3) \times {\mathbb F}_{13}[x]/(x - 9) \cong {\mathbb F}_{13}^3.$$
This is similar to ${\mathbb C}[x]/(x^2+1)$, which is isomorphic to ${\mathbb C}^2$.

In Sage you could do

```
sage: R.<x> = PolynomialRing(GF(13),'x')
sage: f = x^3 - 1
sage: f.factor()
```

and it will come up with

```
(x + 4) * (x + 10) * (x + 12)
```